# What will be the adapter response after server session timeout in worklight 6.2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, session-timeout, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I am working on server session timeout of worklight server. I set serverSessionTimeout=5 in worklight.properties file. I followed all the realm anf authentication process.

After sever session timeout, How can I know that Session is expired from adapter response.

```
ChallengeHandler  :
challengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("MyRealm");

    challengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function(response) {
        console.log("From chalange hanler");
        console.log(response);
    };
```

Adapter call after sesiontimeout (5 minutes) -->

```
var invocationData = {
                adapter: "Auth", 
                procedure: "testSession", 
                parameters: []
            };
        var options = {

            onSuccess: function(res){
                console.log("From test session");
                console.log(res.invocationResult);
            },
            onFailure: function(res){},
        };
        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

Adapter response is same for all the time.

Comment: We are using WL.Client.setHeartbeatInterval () api at the client side, and If the client reached the time-out we specified, then we send an Alert that the session has timed out and we route the user to the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

After a session expiration, an adapter request will be hit with a challenge and the challenge handler process will take place again, doing whatever that you implemented in your challenge handler code. The actual adapter response will arrive after the app successfully "answers" the challenge, that's when the original adapter request will continue its path and the response will arrive back to the app.

Comment: How can I know from client side that session is expired at server side ?

Comment: There is no way that I know of that you can know this from client-side.

Comment: Actually, I want user to logout automatically, If user is inactive for X time with application. Is there any provision for that in worklight?

Comment: You can keep a timer running in the app; any logout from a realm will either have to happen as an action by the user or logic that you have implemented.